# Mounting a local folder as a volume with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis

I am trying to use docker-compose to mount a single volume from a folder in the root directory of my project in order to distribute a configuration file to a series of redis master/slaves and sentinels.

My redis services look like this

```
  # Redis redis-master/slave configurations
  redis-master:
    container_name: "redis-master"
    image: redis/redis-stack:7.0.2-RC3
    networks:
      - redis
      - api
    command:
      - "redis-server /etc/master.conf"
    volumes:
      - ./redis/clustering/redis-master/master.conf:/etc/master.conf
      - ./redis_data/redis-master/:/data/

  redis-slave-0:
    container_name: "redis-slave-0"
    image: redis/redis-stack:7.0.2-RC3
    networks:
      - redis
      - api
    command:
      - "redis-server /etc/slave.conf"
    volumes:
      - ./redis/clustering/redis-slave/slave.conf:/etc/slave.conf
      - ./redis_data/redis-slave-0/:/data/

  redis-slave-1:
    container_name: "redis-slave-1"
    image: redis/redis-stack:7.0.2-RC3
    networks:
      - redis
      - api
    command:
      - "redis-server /etc/slave.conf"
    volumes:
      - ./redis/clustering/redis-slave/slave.conf:/etc/slave.conf
      - ./redis_data/redis-slave-1/:/data/
```

And my docker-compose.yml is located in the same directory as redis with the below structure

```
redis
├── clustering
│   ├── redis-master
│   │   └── master.conf
│   ├── redis-slave
│   │   └── slave.conf
│   └── sentinel
│       └── sentinel.conf
└── redis-reference.conf

4 directories, 4 files
```

When I try to build the project however I am getting this error for each service.

```
Creating redis-slave-0 ... 
Creating redis-master  ... 
Creating postgres      ... done
Creating redis-slave-1 ... error
Creating redis-master  ... error

Creating redis-slave-0 ... error
Creating api           ... done
Creating nginx         ... 

ERROR: for redis-master  Cannot start service redis-master: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "redis-server /etc/master.conf": stat redis-server /etc/master.conf: no such file or directory: unknown

ERROR: for redis-slave-0  Cannot start service redis-slave-0: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "redis-server /etc/slave.conf": stat redis-server /etc/slave.conf: no such file or direc
Creating nginx         ... done

ERROR: for redis-slave-1  Cannot start service redis-slave-1: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "redis-server /etc/slave.conf": stat redis-server /etc/slave.conf: no such file or directory: unknown

ERROR: for redis-master  Cannot start service redis-master: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "redis-server /etc/master.conf": stat redis-server /etc/master.conf: no such file or directory: unknown

ERROR: for redis-slave-0  Cannot start service redis-slave-0: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "redis-server /etc/slave.conf": stat redis-server /etc/slave.conf: no such file or directory: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

The conf file is not being mapped.

Any idea what I'm missing to map this local folder with the relevant file to my services?

Comment: Just to be sure: container `redis-slave-0` starts?

Comment: I didn't notice before but yes there is an error there. I will update teh full error message

Comment: Hmm... I don't think that this will solve it, but could you try rewriting the `command` part such that each part (`redis-server` and `/etc/slave.conf`) is a separate list item? alternatively, you can write it as array: `command: ["redis-server", "/etc/slave.conf"]`)